# Searching using japanese string in documentdb

Tags: python, pymongo, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to search in a collection containing firstname and lastname in japanese characters. Somehow there is no result returned even when there is data in the collection.

Here is the code I have right now which does not yield any result.

```
rgx = re.compile(f".*ひらがな.*", re.IGNORECASE)

query = [
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": {
                {"firstname": rgx},
                {"lastname": rgx}
            }
        }
    }
]

members = db.users.aggregate(query)
```

Any idea on this one?

[DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/) implements the MongoDB v3.6 API. But somehow according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html), `cursor.collation()` is still not supported.

Comment: Are you sure its not your regex?

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation query doesn't look right to me, it should be:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                {"firstname": { $regex: rgx }},
                {"lastname": { $regex: rgx }}
            ]
        }
    }
]
```